# Bitbucket pipelines: Deployment destination dependent on commit author

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment, cicd, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'd like to create a deployment pipeline triggered on PR creation that would deploy to e.g. 'staging1' environment if it's my commit and 'staging2' if it's a commit of other team member (the idea is for each team member to have his/her own environment assigned, but deploy using a shared parametrized pipeline). Is it possible to achieve this and if so, then how?

Answer (score 1):

```
the idea is for each team member to have his/her own environment assigned, but deploy using a shared parametrized pipeline
```

1. You could use definitions for the steps for each environment.

```yaml
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: deploy to staging1
        script:
          - echo "Staging 1"
    - step: deploy to staging2
        script:
          - echo "Staging 2"
```

2. Then just express each colleague branch and restrict his commits to just this branch.
   For each of the branches you could call your needed definitions.

```yaml
branches:    #these will run on every push of the branch
    feature/john.b:
      - step:
          # call needed definition step/s
    feature/pavel.m:
          # call needed definition step/s
```

This gives u flexibility to express multiple definitions steps for one person if needed.